# Copy constructor elision?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

Don't quite understand why this copy constructor is not invoked when I build with debug mode using VC2010.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(int meaningless){}

    SomeClass(const SomeClass& sc)
    {
        cout << "Copy Constructor invoked!" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass test(SomeClass(9999));  // Copy constructor not invoked. 
}
```

I think this has nothing to do with RVO since I am not returning any values.

More interesting, when I make the copy constructor private, the compiler wouldn't even compile even if it omit the copy constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an optimization done by the compiler. According to the language specification, the compiler is allowed to omit the call to the copy-constructor whenever it can.

An accessible  copy-constructor is needed for semantic check only, even though it is not *actually* called. Semantic check is done much before the optimization.

However, if you compile it with `-fno-elide-constructors` option with GCC, then the copy-elision will not be performed, and the copy-constructor will be called. The [GCC doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) says,

> **-fno-elide-constructors**
>
> The C++ standard allows an implementation to omit creating a temporary which is only used to initialize another object of the same type. **Specifying this option disables that optimization, and forces G++ to call the copy constructor in all cases.**

With MSVC10, you can use [/Od](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y(v=vs.100).aspx) which according to the MSDN turns off all optimizations in the program.

*Note* : Wikipedia has an article on [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++11 standard, §12.8.31:

> …This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> …
>
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

Temporary objects get a lot of leeway in C++, and compilers will be pretty aggressive when removing them. If your object had a lifetime of its own in any way, then the copy constructor *would* end up being called.

However, I would definitely expect it to check the copy constructor's access modifier, though I can see an argument that you shouldn't (after all, you just aren't calling the copy constructor). But that probably wouldn't be very good practice, since copy elision is optional.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any possible way or like a compile option for me to turn off that optimization function?

Comment: @YayCplusplus: Yes,. there is. See my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz I really appreciate this..!